# Simple Search, Post and Results page in DotNetNuke v6 and Xmod Pro

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm struggling with Xmod Pro 4.x. All I need to do is create a simple form to pass 3 text fields as parameters to a second page with an xmod template that is trying to receive the parameters. The form is auto built via the xmod designer, and the template obviously is custom.

When I try to post to the page (which does a POST redirect to a "Search Results" page), the xmod template throws this error:

MESSAGE: 
Must declare the scalar variable "@Part".

Here is my ListDataSource snippet:

```
<ListDataSource CommandText="SELECT [Id], 
[PartNumber] 
,[Manufacturer] 
,[Condition] 
,[Description] 
,[Location] 
,[Quantity] 
, 
(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailUrl FROM PKT_PartImage pi WHERE pi.PartNumber = p.PartNumber)     
IS NULL THEN 
'no-photo.png' ELSE 
(SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailUrl FROM PKT_PartImage pi WHERE pi.PartNumber = p.PartNumber) 
END) AS ThumbnailUrl 
, 
(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailUrl FROM PKT_PartImage pi WHERE pi.PartNumber = p.PartNumber)     IS NULL THEN 
'_default' ELSE 
[PartNumber] END) AS ThumbnailPath 
FROM [PKT_Part] p WHERE [PartNumber] LIKE '%' + @Part + '%' OR [Manufacturer] LIKE '%'     + @Mfr + '%' 
OR [PartNumber] LIKE '%' + @Key + '%' OR [Manufacturer] LIKE '%' + @Key + '%' OR     [Condition] LIKE '%' + @Key + '%' 
OR [Description] LIKE '%' + @Key + '%' OR [Location] LIKE '%' + @Key + '%'"> 
<Parameter Name="Part" Value="[[Url:part]]" /> 
<Parameter Name="Mfr" Value="[[Url:mfr]]" /> 
<Parameter Name="Key" Value="[[Url:key]]" /> 
</ListDataSource>
```

Basically, I am getting the error saying it doesn't know what to do with the parameters being passed.  The search form that I'm using was auto-generated by xmod pro and is doing a "redirect POST" to the Results page and that's where the corresponding xmod pro module is throwing the error.

You can see the small search form here (http://pickett.clients.solid-code.com/Home.aspx) and the results page it goes to that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use redirect `method="get"` and not `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the quotes around your value parameters to single quotes instead of double.